# How can I write a simple shell script for temporary display configuration commands?

Tags: shell-script

From time to time I want to change my display resolution, so I type these commands in terminal:

```
xrandr --newmode [newmodedetailsbs]
xrandr --addmode [display] [newmodeid]
xrandr --output [display] --mode [newmodeid]
```

I know what variables to use and they work perfectly, but it's a nuisance to retype them every time I want to change display modes. I'd prefer to create a simple script containing these commands but am having trouble finding basic information on scripting so that I can create the script. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is put the commands that you type in a file, for example, `chres`, then, at the prompt, tell the shell to execute the commands like this:

```
$ sh chres
```

If you want to be able to execute the command from any directory, put the command into your personal `bin` directory (`$HOME/bin`) and make it executable (`~` expands to the full path of your HOME directory:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/bin
$ mv chres ~/bin
$ chmod +x ~/bin/chres
```

Make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your PATH. This will usually be done in you `~.profile` or `~.bashrc`.  Your `~/bin` directory may be added to you PATH automatically if the directory exists.  You can completely log out and log in again to find out if you need to modify your `.profile`.  Type `echo "$PATH"` to find out.

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight. I clicked the checkmark and the upvote caret, but don't have enough rep points for my vote-up to display yet.